# blocking incoming calls when first time running using checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

I want to build app blocking incoming calls. I have one checkbox. If checkbox in condition checked, all incoming calls will be blocker. When the app first time running, checkbox in condition checked. But it doesn't work, it cannot blocking incoming calls. But, when i unchecked and checked it again, it works. So, how to it works when first time it running??

Here is my code :

`public class MainActivity extends Activity {`

```
 CheckBox blockAll_cb;//,blockcontacts_cb;

 TextView teks;

 BroadcastReceiver CallBlocker;
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
 ITelephony telephonyService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    initviews();
    blockAll_cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     CallBlocker =new BroadcastReceiver()
     {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     //Java Reflections
     Class c = null;
     try {
     c = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     Method m = null;
     try {
     m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
     } catch (SecurityException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     m.setAccessible(true);
     try {
     telephonyService = (ITelephony)m.invoke(telephonyManager);
     } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     telephonyManager.listen(callBlockListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
     }//onReceive()
     PhoneStateListener callBlockListener = new PhoneStateListener()
     {


     public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)

     {

         teks=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);

         teks.setText(incomingNumber);




     if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
     {
     if(blockAll_cb.isChecked())
     {
     try {
     telephonyService.endCall();
     } catch (RemoteException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     }

     }
     }
     };
     };//BroadcastReceiver

     IntentFilter filter= new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
     registerReceiver(CallBlocker, filter);
     }
     });
    }




     public void initviews()
     {
     blockAll_cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbBlockAll);
     //blockcontacts_cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbBlockContacts);
     }
     @Override
     protected void onDestroy() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onDestroy();
     if (CallBlocker != null)
     {
     unregisterReceiver(CallBlocker);
     CallBlocker = null;
     }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the initviews() as:

```
 public void initviews()
     {
     blockAll_cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbBlockAll);
     //blockcontacts_cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbBlockContacts);
        blockAll_cb.setChecked(true)
     }
```

**or** add `android:checked="true"` in your xml file.
and then:

```
  if(blockAll_cb.isChecked()==true)
{
  //write call blocking code here
}
else{
  //unblock the calls
}
```

Comment: are you making your checkbox checked by default??if yes,then where is the code??

Comment: i think when first time app running, it can't go to onCallStateChanged Method. Because TextView doens't work too. But, when unchecked and checket id again it works.

Comment: youre not getting me.Ehen u are running ur app for the first time,is your checkbox is checked or unchecked???if checked,then where did you written the code to check that one??